# How to use column names with spaces in stack function in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, sql-function

I tried to unpivot the dataframe and dataframe has folowing structure

| fstcol | col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | 4 |
| one | 2 | 5 |
| One | 3 | 6 |

And I want the dataframe like this :

| fstcol | col_name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | col 1 | 1 |
| one | col 1 | 2 |
| One | col 1 | 3 |
| One | col 2 | 4 |
| one | col 2 | 5 |
| One | col 2 | 6 |

I have written following code to transform:

```
df.selectExpr("fstcol","stack(2, 'col 1', col 1, 'col 2', col 2)")
```

however, I am getting an error as column names contains space. It is unable to get the column values for 'col 1' and 'col 2'.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use backtick:

```py
df.selectExpr("fstcol", "stack(2, 'col 1', `col 1`, 'col 2', `col 2`) as (col_name, value)")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `backticks` like below

```
df.selectExpr("fstcol","stack(2, 'col 1', `col 1`, 'col 2', `col 2`)")
```

Comment: We did the same answer at same time haha